# Is it ok to perform DB operation on UI thread?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using a database to persist the state of a search form. I am using the onPause method to persist the data and the onResume method to restore it. My opinion is that restoring and persisting state should be a blocking operation so I plan to perform the database operations on the UI thread. I know this is generally discouraged but the operations should be quick and I think if they were done asynchronously they could lead to inconsistent UI behaviour.

Any advice

Comment: "the operations should be quick" -- particularly on Android 1.x/2.x, you do not have control over whether or not they are "quick", as that is determined as much by the other running apps as much as it is determined by yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you want the application to not accept user input while the slow operations are being performed, you still don't want to do them in the UI thread. This is for two reasons:

1. Fully non-responsive UIs are a big nono. If you need to lock your user away from interacting with the program, you need to assure him that something is actually going on - anything else is likely to be interpreted as your application being buggy. Use dialogs, toasts and/or progressbars while the application is working, as appropriate.
2. Android will offer users the option of force-closing applications that it thinks are hanging. You don't want this to happen during what is normal behaviour for your application is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want it to be a blocking operation, you have to show the user that some thing is happening. Because when the UI thread is blocked, the screen will not respond to any touch operation of the user. Sp, you can have an **indefinite progress bar** in your `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods till the persistence and restoration is done. 
And obviously you will have to do it in a separate thread. Because if the UI thread is not responding for sometime, android can give the `Application Not Working` error.